# How do I setup a Google Form submission to automatically be sent to a designated email?

Tags: google-apps-script, google-forms

When the user clicks submit I want the responses sent to a designated email address, but also be sent to the user who filled it out and 2 other email addressess.

Comment: Try using the [onFormSubmit() trigger](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/guides/triggers/events?hl=en#form-submit)

Answer (score 0):

Assuming that your email is in column2 of the response sheet in the linked spreadsheet then this should do it.

```
onMyFormSubmit(e) {
  GmailApp.sendMail(e.values[1],'Subject',e.values.join('\n'));
}
```

Another way to do a similar thing:

Imagine you have a response sheet that looks like this:

| Timestamp | One | Two | Three | Email Address |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| Sat Jan 16 2021 17:02:07 GMT-0700 (Mountain Standard Time) | 1 | 2 | 3 | Redacted |
| Sat Jan 16 2021 17:05:53 GMT-0700 (Mountain Standard Time) | 1 | 2 | 3 | Redacted |
| Sat Jan 16 2021 17:18:15 GMT-0700 (Mountain Standard Time) | 1 | 2 | 3 | Redacted |
| Sat Jan 16 2021 17:20:36 GMT-0700 (Mountain Standard Time) | 1 | 2 | 3 | Redacted |

Then you can use code like this to generate an email to the collected email.

```
function onMyFormSubmit(e) {
  const sh=e.range.getSheet();
  //Logger.log(JSON.stringify(e));
  const msg=Utilities.formatString('\nEmail:%s\nOne:%s\nTwo:%s\nThree:%s',e.namedValues['Email Address'][0],e.namedValues.One[0],e.namedValues.Two[0],e.namedValues.Three[0]);
  //Logger.log(msg);
  GmailApp.sendEmail(e.namedValues["Email Address"][0], 'subject',msg);
}
```

And you will get an email that looks like this:

[image]